# Create collage with multiple images

Tags: javascript

I'm having quite a challenge... I have a web page where the user clicks on images, those images have to be added together to create only one image and the user must be able to download that group of images as only one...

I have no idea how to do this, any tip or info so I can start researching?

Here is an example I found searching with google:

In my case each of the squares of the image would be a totally different image but this Is what I have to achieve...

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure that you'll need a server side script to combine all of your images and send the result back to the user as a single image. In Javascript maybe, but maybe, a Canvas element can create your image (HTML5 ofc).

Comment: As SYNCRo said, this will require back-end functionality.  Do you have a preferred back-end language so we can give tips?

Comment: I'm working with rails 3... I though it was a client-side thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find the way to do this server side... ImageMagick it's the answer and the RMagick gem if you guys are using ruby!

There is a command called montage that will do the job! Here is more information about it! http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Hope it helps to anybody there!